# Excel hyperlink to a specific cell

Tags: excel

I need to hyperlink a cell in one spreadsheet to a corresponding cell in another spreadsheet.
So for example, C7 in sheet1 has a hyperlink that will bring you to C7 in sheet 2.  I need to do this for a fairly large spreadsheet and each hyperlink has to be different.  Is there a way to do this on mass without having to go to each cell and set the hyperlink for each cell independently?  (Using MS Office 2010)

Comment: Do you know VBA? Also, is it always a 1 to 1 relationship, where it takes you to the exact cell on another sheet?

Answer (score 28):

You can use the following excel formula: (paste into cell C7)

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2!"&CELL("address",C7),"click")
```

Notes:

- `[Book1.xlsx]` must be the name of the workbook
- `Sheet2` must nbe name name of the sheet you are hyperlinking to

Essentially it uses the above two as a prefix to the link, and then the address of the current cell (c7 in the case of your example) to finish the link.

The above example once pasted into cell C7 can be dragged down to generate links based on the formula cell's address.

**Update:** (per chris)

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!"&CELL("address"),"click")
```

Comment: This is a nice formula. If there are already values in your cell you can replace the "click" with those values or formulas to get those values.

Comment: Good formula, but can be improved.  Since OP want to link in the same workbook, replace `[Book Name]` with `#`.  Leaving out the `C7` in the call to `CELL` references the cell the formula is in.  If linked sheet name includes spaces or other special characters you need to wrap sheet name in `' '`  So use `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!"&CELL("address"),"click")`

Comment: Worked syntax for me : `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!C7","click")`

Comment: This works in my experience: `=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",'Sheet2'!C7),"Click")`. Better because it avoids harcoding the sheet name (if you rename the sheet, nothing breaks).

Comment: @guidupuy it worked. thank you alot

Answer (score 12):

Three years late, I would go a bit further and use ADDRESS(row,column) to build the cell address, rather than use CELL() which is a volatile function. If you're building a large spreadsheet and using a volatile function more than just a handful of times, you're going to notice the performance hit.

ADDRESS() is not volatile, so it doesn't trigger a recalculation all the time, and it's also more flexible to use.

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"click")
```

Replace ROW() and COLUMN() with whatever number you require.

For example, for a specific cell in Sheet2 use

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!C7),COLUMN(Sheet2!C7)),"click")
```

If you want Sheet2, third column, and 1 row below (relatively), use

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!"&ADDRESS(ROW()+1,3),"click")
```

Comment: To carry this one step further, can a link be made to apply to just a portion of the text inside a cell? I have some cells full of explanatory text, and would like to create a hyperlink from just an asterisk that jumps to another cell, similar to clicking on a footnote in a document; is this possible in Excel 2013?

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to nitpick, it also can look like this:

```
" - starting quote
# - local book (spreadsheet)
'Sheet2' - name of sheet you are going to (has to be in single quotes)
!C7 - cell in the other sheet you are trying to go to
"- ending quote
, - separating comma used in the hyperlink syntax
"click" - link text to appear in cell
```

Final function syntax:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!C7","click")
```