# Reference specific cells in excel

Tags: vba, excel

So what I would like to do is: I have in "Worksheet A" a cell called 'Commerial use
' and in "Worksheet B" I have the same cell "Commerial use"

My goal is to link those two. So, for example if I click on the "Commerial use
" cell in "Worksheet A" I should jump straight to "Worksheet B" to the cell "Commerial use
".

I have tried using hyperlinks, they let you jump to the defined worksheet, but not directly into the right cell

So I am not sure if i am gonna need VBA for that or if there is a fromula that could help me ?

Comment: How did you try the hyperlinks?  They seem to work fine here.

Comment: @pnuts thanks for the infp sure i have been trying for a bit but with no clear result

Comment: @RonRosenfeld they work but you cant do a cell to cell link what my gole is

Comment: Just to clarify some details; are these cells *named*; (if you click on them instead of showing the address next to the formula bar it shows the name you've given the cell). I assume not because `Commerial use` is an invalid name, and you can't use the same name twice within a workbook (even on separate sheets), but just checking. Also, are the cells you're linking in the same place  (e.g. `Sheet1!C7` and `Sheet2!C7`), and does the formatting of their contents matter or just the text. If the latter, then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30907498/6609896) - replace "click" with your text

Comment: Yes, they do go `cell-to-cell`.  That is why I asked how did you do it?  And they will do that whether I use a Named cell or a cell reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you did this, but here it goes cell-to-cell

- Select a cell you want to link from
- From the Right click menu, select `Link`
- Enter either the named cell reference, or the Sheet and Cell reference

[image]

- Click OK and you should be done.

Comment: yeah i just saw that you can do it via cell referance thank you so much GJ ! :)