# What is the fastest way to add hyperlinks to worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says.
Adding values first to array and then to worksheet works really fast (15ms for 8000 cells, compared to 350ms when looping on to worksheet). But is there a similar way to add hyperlinks very qickly? Looping direcly on worksheet each cell takes its tool really hard.
I would like to keep same visible value for all cells with custom hyperlinks.

Edit:

```
                        With Me.RangeTarget(2, mvaln).Resize(rowi + 1)
                        Select Case qcolumn.Preprocess
                        Case 1
                            For i = 0 To UBound(rsrows, 2)
                                localcol(i, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(rsrows(j, i))
                            Next
                            .Value2 = localcol
                        Case 2
                            For i = 0 To UBound(rsrows, 2)
                                localcol(i, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Degrees(rsrows(j, i))
                            Next
                            .Value2 = localcol
                        Case 3
                             For i = 0 To UBound(rsrows, 2)
                                localcol(i, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(rsrows(j, i))
                            Next
                            .Value2 = localcol
                        Case 4
                            For i = 0 To UBound(rsrows, 2)
                                If LenB(rsrows(j, i)) > 0 Then
                                    Me.RangeTarget(2 + i, mvaln).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.RangeTarget(2 + i, mvaln), Address:=rsrows(j, i), TextToDisplay:="Link"
                                Else
                                    Me.RangeTarget(2 + i, mvaln).ClearContents
                                End If
                            Next
                        Case 5
               ... ... ...
```

This is my current code... at 'case 4' I'd like to avoid looping. `rsrows(j, i)` is value that needs to be put into sheet. At case 1 to case 3 you can see I put all in temporary array and then on worksheet... but can't do the same with hyperlinks to speed things up.

Comment: So did you write a loop that cycles through each cell and adds a hyperlink?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are after? And the code you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what value `rsrows(j, i)` contains.  Whether it is a URL/File Path or an internal cell reference.  Either way, just use the `=HYPERLINK()` formula with either `.Value2 =` or `.Formula =`

```
For i = 0 To UBound(rsrows, 2)
    If LenB(rsrows(j, i)) > 0 Then
        localcol(i, 0) = "=HYPERLINK(" & rsrows(j, i) & "," & "Link" & ")"
    Else
        localcol(i, 0) = vbNullString
    End If
Next
.Formula = localcol
'.Value2 = localcol
```

P.S. If you need some help linking to cells within the file take a look this post:
[Excel hyperlink to a specific cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115848/excel-hyperlink-to-a-specific-cell)

Comment: .Formula = localcol apparently doesn't accept variant list.

Comment: Nevermind. This actually works, but I have to be careful to additionaly filter out special characters. Performance with no filter characters is about 10-20% faster. It's also not true hyperlink as it can be exposed and modified. Also you need to set cell format to "General" to process the formula.