# Want to hyperlink to a certain cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a dynamic hyperlink. My data validation has numbers 1 - 222. The row is 8, this does not change.

When the user selects 57 from the drop down I want a link that takes them to Row 8 Column 57.

Any ideas on how to build this?

Comment: Please use search (internal or external) before posting new questions. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115848/excel-hyperlink-to-a-specific-cell

Answer (score 1):

where your drop down is in B1:

```
=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1)),999)&"!"&ADDRESS(8,B1,1,1),"goto")
```